# Firefox/Firebug JavaScript console.log not working in for loop in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

There are three lines with `console.log` in my code here:

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function()
{//console.log('window.onload');
 var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('table').0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

 for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)
 {
  console.log('i,1 = '+i);

  (function(i)
  {
   console.log('i,2 = '+i);

   if (tr[i].getElementsByTagName('input').length>1)
   {
    tr[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].addEventListener('click', function(event) {sessionStorage.hash_self_tr = i;}, false);}})(i);
   }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr><td>1<input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>2<input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>3<input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

**In *Firefox* why do the second and third `console.log` logger not trigger unless I uncomment the first `console.log`?** This works fine in Chrome.

Comment: do you have an element with the `id` table

Comment: can you post an example that we can run ?

Comment: @CodeiSir Created a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/kk6ypfqb/ though Firefox gave me an iframe sandbox security error there. This question is more of a curiosity, I *really* have no desire to increase my personal ratio of posting bug reports that never get fixed.

Comment: It does not run the unload function so i changed it https://jsfiddle.net/kk6ypfqb/2/ - but it works just fine, i get all logs

Comment: I clicked the "Run code snippet" button in your question in Firefox (and in Chrome) and it logs six messages. Is that not the desired behavior, or is that not what happens for you when you click the "Run code snippet" button?

Comment: Which version of Firefox and Firebug do you use?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Firefox 9 (38 ESR) and the latest version of Firebug (2.0.13).

Answer (score 0):

seem like firebug console is no longer support or update for latest firefox browser.

firefox have it own developer tool coming out no long ago, have all the features firebug have.

http://etenbo.com/why-firebug-for-firefox-javascript-console-log-is-not-working/